# Xcode 12 doesn't Support PINCache

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12.3

Previously I have used PINCache in Xcode 11.5 version.
Now I update the Xcode 12.3 version.
PINCache will not support my Xcode it will give following error:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(PINMemoryCache
> *__strong, NSString *__strong, __strong id)' to parameter of type 'PINCacheObjectBlock _Nonnull' (aka 'void (^)(id  _Nonnull
> __strong, NSString * _Nonnull __strong, id  _Nullable __strong)')

Comment: What version of PINCache are you using? Have you tried updating to the latest version? Have you looked at their repo to see if they have an issue open for this? Please be more descriptive with your questions.

Comment: I have using PINCache 3.0.1-beta version.This is latest repo of the pincache.It will run in Xcode 11.5 .